# Adding select box with input text in one row

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a list, that looks like a table with a text from right side and input file on the left side.
it looks like this:

**input**        |                 **label**

**input**        |            **label**

and so on...

I want to add a row with one `select box`, `input tex`t and `label`, like this:

**selectBox | input        |     label**

so I added this code to the list

```
  <li>
                              <label for="a2">number2</label>
                              <span id="a2" style="width:30%; float:right;">
                                   <input type="text" id="Text5"></span>

                             <select name="select-choice-1" id="select3" >
                                    <option selected="selected" value=""/>
                                    <option value="22">22</option>
                                    <option value="33">33</option>
                                    <option value="44">44</option>
                                    <option value="55">55</option>
                            </select>

                         </li>
```

It looks exactly as I want, only with one problem that the `input text` is disabled (I cant enter any text to it)
if I **replce all the select box with simple input text its looks and work ok**.

I noticed that after wraping the select div with : `<div data-role="fieldcontain">`

```
 <div data-role="fieldcontain">   

     <select name="select-choice-1" id="select3" >
                                    <option selected="selected" value=""/>
                                    <option value="22">22</option>
                                    <option value="33">33</option>
                                    <option value="44">44</option>
                                    <option value="55">55</option>
   </select>

 </div>
```

And then it works correctly but it getting down to a new line, and dont looks like I want.

How can I fix this issue and stay with the design I describes above, in fact what should I change so my first examle will work properly.

Comment: add one of the following styles to the div `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this method
html

```
<element1></element1>
<element2></element2>
<element3></element3>
<br class="clear" />
```

css

```
element1,element2,element3{
    float: left;
}
br.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is I float:left all elements. You need to float left the 3 of them, or they will act weird. Also be careful that the li element may lose it's height, so you should add overflow:hidden to it